# Can naturalized Argentina citizens renounce their citizenship?

Tags: citizenship, argentina

Argentinians born in Argentina cannot renounce their citizenship

Is it the same for naturalized ones?

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia on [Argentine nationality law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentine_nationality_law):

> Dual nationality is accepted in Argentina. However, dual nationals are
> recognized only as Argentine nationals within Argentine territory and
> must enter Argentina using an Argentine passport, except when visiting
> with a passport of nations with which Argentina has a reciprocity
> agreement. They must present the identity card to prove the
> Argentine nationality. In case the country does not have an agreement
> they can enter up to 180 days, after that time, they must leave with
> the Argentine passport.
>
> Unlike most other countries, Argentine nationality cannot be renounced
> and can only be revoked if it was obtained through criminal means,
> such as fraudulent documentation.
>
> Consequently an Argentine national may not be able to acquire the
> nationality of a country that requires renunciation of other national
> identities; however, many countries waive this requirement if
> renouncing the other nationality is impossible.

So, it appears that Argentine nationality cannot be voluntarily renounced, even if you are a naturalized Argentine national, even though the Argentine government can revoke the nationality of an Argentine national involuntarily if this status is obtained through criminal fraud.

This rule appears to date from 1934, when the the Inter-American Convention on the Nationality of Women signed by the Argentine delegation to the Pan-American Union's Montevideo conference in 1933 became effective in 1934, without legal reservations. This reformed prior law under which Argentine women who married a non-Argentine husband lost their Argentine nationality. The law under this treaty was confirmed in 1947, when the Minister of Foreign Affairs issued another circular reiterating that marriage neither bestowed nor relinquished nationalization for a spouse, but that foreign wives could be issued Argentine passports.

Also, strictly speaking, it is Argentine nationality rather than Argentine citizenship that cannot be renounced, and different countries distinguish between nationality and citizenship in different ways. In Argentina:

> Argentine nationality law regulates the manner in which one acquires,
> or is eligible to acquire, Argentine nationality. Nationality, as used
> in international law, describes the legal methods by which a person
> obtains a national identity and formal membership in a nation.
> Citizenship refers to the relationship between a nation and a
> national, after membership has been attained.

For example, Argentina could establish a criminal code provision that punishes some crime with forfeiture of some or all of the rights associated with citizenship (e.g. the right to vote), without causing that person to lose their Argentine nationality. But, someone could not, of their own accord, renounce Argentine nationality to, for example, avoid an obligation where it is imposed upon Argentine national on the eve of a war, to be conscripted into military service in the Argentine military.

This said, aside from military conscription (which [last occurred in 1995](https://www.povertyactionlab.org/evaluation/military-conscription-and-crime-argentina#:%7E:text=From%201901%20to%201995%2C%20military,male%20citizen%27s%20national%20ID%20number.) in Argentina), it isn't obvious that there are any great benefits to be had from ceasing to have Argentine nationality that arise under Argentine law.

Argentina, for example, unlike the United States, [does not tax its nationals on their worldwide income](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Argentina) and instead taxes only income connected with Argentina. Argentina does have a tax on the worldwide net worth of some people who are Argentine nationals, but [only if the Argentine national is also a tax resident of Argentina](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/global/Documents/Tax/dttl-tax-argentinahighlights-2021.pdf).

Other countries may ordinarily require renunciation of citizenship, for example, to become a citizen of a new country or to serve in public office in their country. But, as noted above, many countries with such requirements waive that requirement under their law in the case of people of Argentine nationality, because it cannot be renounced or surrendered under Argentine law.